# Travelling to Amalfi coast. Is it safe going by car?

Tags: safety, italy, automobiles, naples

My girlfriend and I are planning a short trip to visit Amalfi coast and Naples.

We planned to arrive in Salerno and spend two days visiting the cities and the beaches of Amalfi coast (swimming etc). Then, on the third day move to Naples and visit the city.

I am a little bit concerned to go there by car since a few friends advised me against due to stealing and damaging potential.

I would like to know if there are safe parkings along this itinerary (I guess we can find an hotel with guarded parking in Salerno and leave the car there for the first two nights);

- Is it safe enough during the day to park the car in Amalfi, Sorrento, Positano etc and visit the city?
- Is there a parking in Naples easily reachable by car (maybe in suburbs) where I can safely leave the car for the day we visit that city and from where we can easily reach the center with public transportation?

Comment: I suggest you rewrite the question. "Is it safe to....." questions are frowned upon because we have no idea what you consider "safe". For example: "I search a guarded parking place near the Amalfi coast".

Comment: What are you worried about???? The total crime rate in the US is 5 times higher than Italy.

Comment: @Hilmar While true in general, [Italy](http://knoema.de/atlas/Italien/topics/Kriminalit%c3%a4tsstatistiken) is worse for car theft than the [USA](http://knoema.de/atlas/Vereinigte-Staaten-von-Amerika/topics/Kriminalit%c3%a4tsstatistiken). Car theft is 200.6 vs 160.8, all vehicle theft is 295.1 vs 215.8 for 100 000 people/year. In contrast the USA has a whopping 541,5 vs 190 (100 000 people/year) for burglary and much worse rates for all violent crimes.

Comment: @Hilmar Most crime is highly localized, so country-by-country, province-by-province, and like comparisons are not especially useful. Washington, D.C. is home to some of the safest urban neighborhoods in the country, and some of its most dangerous.

Comment: I was just puzzled by the questions: I've been in Italy many times, my wife has lived there and my brother in law still does. Never had a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Anecdotal)
I would never drive the amalfi coast.

We took the bus between Sorrento and Amalfi and it was just mind boggling crazy;

I suggest parking in Salerno and take a bus to your destination along the coast; after that, you can safely drive inland to Naples.

Public bus timetable :
http://www.sitabus.it/en/salerno-to-amalfi-coast-bus-timetable/

Video of the Amalfi coast line road.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tsv7rMEJx3M

Comment: A agree. Save yourself the hassle if you are not used to driving in very narrow lanes that are ~5-10cm wider than you car.